# std::vector zeroing out trivial types

Tags: c++

The author of chrono claims [here](https://youtu.be/P32hvk8b13M?t=238) that if you have a vector of chrono::seconds, it does not initialize by default. I'm wondering how that's accurate, e.g. if I initialize a vector of a struct that wraps an int, e.g. the assertion never triggers below. Does this have to do with zero init pages allocated or does the standard guarantee this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

struct X {
    int y;
};

int main() { 
    std::vector<X> vec(10);
    for (auto &el : vec) { 
        assert(el.y == 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example `struct` has some fundamentally different properties from `chrono::duration`. `X` is an aggregate, while `chrono::duration` is instead a non-aggregate with defaulted default constructor. That affects the meaning of different initialization methods, although for use in `std::vector` it will end up with zero-initialization either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read e.g. [this `std::vector` constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), the definition

```
std::vector<X> vec(10);
```

is number 4 in that reference list (since C++11), which uses [*default insertion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable) for the elements.

And default insertion does (by *default*) [*value initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) which for an *aggregate* like your structure does [*aggregate initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) which in turn will make you `int` member

> copy-initialized from an empty initializer list

Which will set it to zero.

There are a lot of steps to go through, but it all ends up with the well-defined behavior of initializing all `y` members to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like he meant *array* instead of vector, because vector elements are always initialized.

```
std::array<second, 100> arr1;                        // not initialized
std::array<second, 100> arr2{};                      // zero initialized
std::unique_ptr<second[]> arr3{ new second[100] };   // not initialized
std::unique_ptr<second[]> arr4{ new second[100]{} }; // zero initialized
std::vector<second> vec(100);                        // zero initialized
```

Comment: Note that `std::array<second, 100> arr2{};` is really [*value* initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), which (through a few hoops) will make all elements zero.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know that technically "uninitialized" should be "default initialized" and "zero initialized" should be "value initialized", but those terms get in the way of people understanding what's going on.